# XAMARIN, llamar a otra actividad

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin

Me gustaria poder moverme en Xamarin por diferentes Activity, desde el MainActivity desde un button puedo ir a la siguiente actividad (MenuNumeros):

```
 base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnNumeros);
        button.Click += delegate
        {
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MenuNum);

        };
```

Pero desde este activity necesito volver a ir a un tercer activity que no logro que me funcione, lo hago desde el boton btnSecuencial y la nueva actividad se llama Secuencial:

```
 base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MenuNum);

        Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnSecuencial);
        button.Click += delegate
        {
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Secuencial);

        };
```

En que estoy fallando?

Muchas gracias

Comment: en que contexto pones ese codigo ? obtienes algun mensaje de error?

Comment: La segunda parte del código que es donde tengo el problema lo tengo dentro de  protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        de mi clase MenuNumeros que es un Activity. No, no tengo errores, simplemente cuando inicio la aplicacion y llevo hasta esta actividad pulso el boton y no hace nada. Gracias por la contestacion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En vez de cambiar el contenido de la vista mediante `SetContentView`, puedes iniciar actividades nuevas a través de `StartActivity`.

Así, en vez de

```
button.Click += (sender, args) =>
{
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MenuNum);
};
```

Harías lo siguiente:

```
button.Click += (sender, args) =>
{
    StartActivity(typeof(MenuNumeros));
};
```

Donde `MenuNumeros` es el nombre de la clase que hereda de activity

```
public class MenuNumeros : Activity
{
  protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
  {
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    ...
  }
}
```

De igual manera, en el evento `Click` del botón en  la actividad `MenuNumeros`, en vez de poner un `SetContentView` podrías usar `StartActivity(typeof(Secuencial))`.

Puedes referirte a la documentación oficial de Xamarin para más detalles:

https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/fundamentals/activity/start_an_activity/

Answer (score 1):

Claro, siempre para iniciar otra actividad se debe llamar con:

```
StartActivity(typeof(actividadAiniciar));
```

La parte `“actividadAiniciar”` es el nombre de tu nueva actividad a ejecutar.
Esto significa que debes crear una actividad diferente para cada ventana a mostrar.

Y para regresar nuevamente a la anterior actividad puedes hacerlo con el botón `“Back”` o poniendo en el control que ejecutará la acción. Por lo general ubicado en la parte superior izquierda: `Finish();`

Con esto te quiero decir que no vayas a poner nuevamente la instrucción StartActivity para volver ya que te llenarías de instancias de la misma actividad.